# Why are Ethereum API RPC and not REST?

Tags: rpc, api-design, endpoint

I come from traditional web application development background where the standard is RESTful APIs (and recently with some GrapghQL API showing up).

When I started interacting with ethereum endpoints, especially the one exposed by geth, I find they are all RPC.

Was there a technical reason for this decision? Or it just *happened*

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this resource about why Ethereum uses JSON-RPC and not REST:

[Why do blockchain networks like Ethereum utilize JSON RPC calls and not REST APIs or graphQL?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85245/why-do-blockchain-networks-like-ethereum-utilize-json-rpc-calls-and-not-rest-api)